# how to solve "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" while using posting data while fetch?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I was using fetch post method to post this array of object to my backend. But dont know why I am getting this error.

```
const inventory = [
    {
        name: "phone",
        price: 1200,
    },
    {
        name: "Laptop",
        price: 12000,
    },
    {
        name: "I mac",
        price: 120000,
    },
]

fetch('localhost:5000/inventory', {
    method: 'POST',
    header: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(inventory)
})
```

Comment: your server is likely sending HTML - probably becaus `localhost:5000/inventory` would end up being a completely incorrect URL - check in the browser developer tools to see what the requested URL is .... try `//localhost:5000/inventory` if it's a cross origin request ... or `/inventory` if it's same origin ... a url like you're using is path only, therefore, the server part of the pages URL is prepended to the request ... you need to learn how url's work in a browser